# Does Ubuntu support NFC hardware on Nexus 7?

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, nfc

I was wondering if the NFC hardware on Nexus 7 is supported by Ubuntu.
As I understand, the Nexus 7 contains the PN544 chip set. I installed the PC/SC service (pcscd) which works with external USB based NFC devices out of the box. Is it possible to use this service with the internal NFC chip?

Comment: Are you intending this for **12.10** or **13.04** (rather than 12.04) ?

Comment: Has anyone used NFC on desktop Ubuntu? (rather than ARM-based)

Comment: @david6: (1) Yes, I am actually using 12.10 and can upgrade to 13.04 if necessary. I updated the tag accordingly. (2) Using external USB based NFC devices on Ubuntu (both intel and arm based) works out of the box. However, my question is specific to the pn544 chip set built into the Nexus device.